# Using mutate with case_when in R

Tags: dplyr, case-when

I'm trying to write a function to mutate columns in R.  I think this code will make it easier to explain:

```
a = c(0,0,0,1)
b = c(1,1,1,1)
c = c(0,1,1,0)
d = c(1,1,0,0)
df = data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I also have a secondary list that gives values to each columns: a=100, b=100, c=200, d=300.  There are many more columns, but say I created three lists:

```
onehundred = c('a', 'b')
twohundred = c('c')
threehundred = c('d')
```

I want to add new columns, called 'a_2', 'b_2', 'c_2', and 'd_2' such that each element in each column is multiplied by the value (so a_2 = c(0,0,0,100), etc.).  How would I go about that?  Currently, I have:

```
func = function(column){
  df%>%
    mutate(!!paste0(column, '_2') := casewhen(
      column %in% onehundred ~ 100*column,
      column %in% twohundred ~ 200*column,
      column %in% threehundred ~ 300*column,
}
c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')%>%
  map(func)
```

So when I run the function, it does not work.  However, if I replace `100*column` with

```
100*"a"
```

(but a is inside the tick marks, not quotes) the code works for that single column.  How can I run it for each column?
Note 1: I expect this function to produce a list of 4 dataframes with 5 columns each (a,b,c,d + the one mutated column).  I know how to reduce these into one dataframe.
Note 2: Alternatively, I would settle for three columns labeled 'onehundred', 'twohundred', and 'threehundred', where each column counts the number of 1's for each observation.  For instance, it would produce:

```
onehundred = c(1,1,1,2)
twohundred = c(0,1,1,0)
threehundred = c(1,1,0,0)
```